# What function allows to ask wether a variable is an integer inside an if statement

Tags: python, string, integer

```
user_input = int(input("Please enter a multiplier!"))
if user_input == int:
    for multiplier in range (1,12,1): #this is where i'm kinda stuck
        print multiplier, " x ", user_input, " = ", multiplier * user_input
elif user_input == str:
        print "Please enter a quantitative numerical value as a multiplier, and try again, thanks!"
```

this is what I am doing:
    user_input = float(input("Please enter a multiplier!"))
    for multiplier in range (1,13,1):
            print multiplier, "x", user_input, " = ", multiplier * user_input

this is the output
    1 x 9.9  =  9.9
    2 x 9.9  =  19.8
    3 x 9.9  =  29.7
    4 x 9.9  =  39.6
    5 x 9.9  =  49.5
    6 x 9.9  =  59.4
    7 x 9.9  =  69.3
    8 x 9.9  =  79.2
    9 x 9.9  =  89.1
    10 x 9.9  =  99.0
    11 x 9.9  =  108.9
    12 x 9.9  =  118.8

```
#Yet if the user inputs a string (a letter) how should I convert it?
```

Comment: Hi. Please at the very least take the time to properly format the code in  your question, so we can understand it. Thank you.

Comment: If it's not an integer, you'll get a `ValueError`. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/3001761

Comment: user_input = int(input("Please enter a multiplier!"))   
if user_input == int:
    for multiplier in range (1,12,1):
        print multiplier, " x ", user_input, " = ", multiplier * user_input
elif user_input == str:
        print "Please enter a quantitative numerical value as a multiplier, and try again, thanks!"

Comment: im new here how do you format it?

Comment: Don't put code in comments, for a start. http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: If you are posting from a PC, there are all kinds of formatting helpers above the text window when you edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `type` or `insinstance` of python `builtin` module, like,

```
if type(user_input) is int:
    # your code
```

`type` returns the type of the obect. Or using `insinstance`,

```
if isinstance(user_input, int):
    # your code
```

`isinstance` return `True` if the object is instance of a class or it's subclass.

Now, in your code you are already casting the `user_input` an `int` in the first line. So there is no point to check if `user_input` is `int` or `str`. The programme will also raise an error if you give an input other than digit.

Comment: please mention the reason for down voting so that the answer can be improved. otherwise there is no point.

Comment: right, this makes so much sense! but if i want to generate a multiplication timetable depending on the user input  and imagine the user inputs a letter then, I wish the program to print an error message saying that a quantitative value is needed. Let me try and portray it, thanks in advance!!

Comment: remove the int casting. `user_input = input("Please enter a multiplier!")`

Comment: excuse my depiction I'm new at this, I did think of doing so but then the output is incorrect, as when multipling 2 by the user input (say 3) will output 33 instead of 6

Comment: So basically I'm defining the input as a numerical value so the program acts as such to generate the multiplication @salmanwahed

Comment: Your question was finding the type of your input. Accept the answer if it solves your question. Post new question if you have further problems.

Comment: Okay how do you think I should ask the question? @salmanwahed please help

Comment: Read this: [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).